# None of my Windows 10 computers will update

Tags: windows-10

Ever since the 1703 update, my Windows 10 computers have refused to update.  They'll proceed to some low single digit percentage of download, and just stick there.  Network activity stops.  Can leave them on overnight, no change.

I've done the SoftwareDistribution cleanout and that just starts them over at 0%.  They'll get stuck at the same % point as before (it varies based on the computer, but is consistent on that individual computer).

Is there a patch I should go and get manually that will fix Windows 10 updating?  Some other trick other than trying to clean out the SoftwareDistribution?  I've even tried turning all off but one just in case they're doing internal distribution and contaminating each other somehow, but still the same problem.

Comment: Is Windows update service running? Did you try with manual package update from https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx

Comment: What specific build are you running?  You can use winver to provide us this information.  I am trying to determine if you are already running .540 or not.  I have specific reasons I am asking for this information.

Comment: If you install [KB4038788](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4038788) manually does anything change?

Comment: Updated service is running.  Looks like I'm on .332, will try the KB manually next!

Comment: Download/run manually worked fine on the first computer.  Bumped me to .608!  I wonder if that'll fix future updates?

Comment: All computers updated from downloaded KB now, no issues with doing it that way.  I guess we'll see if automatic starts working again.  I sure hope so!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the Fall Creator's Update (2017) fixed it.  It would not install automatically, but forcing it through the media creator kit worked and resolved all my updating issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the anti-virus and Windows Firewall temporarily for test.
If the issue persists, run this Microsoft offical Windows Update troubleshooter tool:
[Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4027498/windows-run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps)

You also could read Windows Update Log to see if any clue:

[How to read Windows Update logs in Windows 10 Version 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3036646/how-to-read-windows-update-logs-in-windows-10-version-1607)